# efficient way to look for reciprocal entries in matrix

Tags: bash, perl, matrix, processing-efficiency

I have many matrices with ~1,000,000,000 rows by 10 columns. Each of them takes ~100G storage and about 2.5 minutes to just count the number of lines, so I need to be efficient in processing them for time and resources' sake.

The most important columns are #1 and #2 and #10. In one example matrix there are ~2,000,000 unique entries in #1 and ~10,000,000 entries in #2. All #1 entries exist in #2, but not all #2 entries exist in #1.

I would like to ask for your advice on how to efficiently find all cases where there exists a reverse occurrence between column #1 and #2. In other words: find all pairs between #1 and #2 where there exist #1-#2 and #2-#1.

I need to do something with #10 once each case is found.

There are few ways I can think of but have not tested any.

- I can pre-process the file and store all unique #1 entries and #2 entries and make combinations of them before going through the file.
- I can read through the file and collect the pairs, create the reverse case and store in some kind of hash for future lookup. This however makes the hash rather large and requires going through the file twice.
- I can read through the file and collect the pairs, sort the pairs alphabetically (so always A-B) and store count in a hash. As I read through the file, a quick lookup for previous occurrence.
- I can also try using gdbm.

What do you think would be the best solution?

Any alternative suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these matrices in flat files? Put them into a database. Someone has been irresponsible to allow a billion-line flat file to exist in the first place.

Comment: @Borodin These are flat files. This is a merged result of multi-parallel processing of small chunks of a huge input. Database is an option.

Comment: I think you should go for a MySQL or PostgreSQL (or possibly SQLite) database. Put indexes on the first two columns, and the rest should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually done that in the past with MySQL. That sounds like a valid approach. The only constraint I have is that this task has to be done only once on each matrix, so not sure if database implementation would be the most appropriate. Point well taken though!

Comment: Also, reading 100GB in 2.5 minutes requires a disk that will read at over 700MB/s. Is this on an SSD?

Comment: No, I just have quite fast hdd with speeds closer to 1GB/s.

Comment: You have a miracle! I have never known a HDD that will read faster than 150MB/s. There must be some significant caching going on.

Comment: Interestingly, the number I'm quoting is supposed be without the caching effect of a [disk datarate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance). That doesn't mean there is no caching happening.

Comment: I strongly second Borodin's suggestion with the RDBMS. Even if you are just doing it once per file, if it cuts the development time **and** the run time of the process significantly, it's a good approach. It also makes it easier to debug because you can run queries on the DB as long as you develop it. There are tools on CPAN that make starting your own [mysql](http://p3rl.org/Test::mysqld) or [postgres](Test::PostgreSQL) instance from Perl trivial. However, using SQL import features for the files might be way faster.

Comment: You can also start by setting your mysqld's database directory to where the file is, make a database with the [CSV engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html) and then switch it to InnoDB to do indexing.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. I will consider that given both of you suggested DBs now.